# Cannot crash a faulty logic with my unit test

Tags: c

So I'm making a unit test for my program, but there is one case where I know it should crash but I can't seem to make it do so, here is an example of the case I have.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    buf[2] = { 0 };
    int     i = -1;

    printf("%c", buf[i]);
    return (0);
}
```

From my understanding, it should crash in some kind of entropy, but all it seems to do is read from where the pointer is in memory. Or is this behavior supposed to be normal and there is no way where it would crash no matter what kind of tests we run?

Comment: You cannot test for undefined behavior, because what is supposed to happen is *undefined*. This does not look at all like a unit test, BTW.

Comment: This was supposed to be just an example and not the actual code snippet and unit test; This was just for the sake of minimalism, but I understand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, example code should be minimal, but it should *also* be complete. You should post the actual unit test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is supposed to be *undefined*. Which means it can crash, or it can print garbage, or it can print nothing because a compiler is allowed to assume that undefined behavior doesn't happen and to not generate any code leading to it... or it can kill you (literally) if it finds its way into production code of a safety-critical application.

If you really want to test for it, you need to rely on knowledge of your compiler's behavior and on implementation-defined tricks for your particular platform, such as, on Linux with MMU support, aligning the `buf` onto the start of the memory page and marking the preceding memory page as `mprotect(PROT_NONE)` - then you will get `SIGSEGV` when trying to access it.